# Typescript Class or Interface to represent a json HttpClient.get response

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular2 when I call httpClient.get() on some api, it always returns the same json object structure, which may have some nested attributes, i.e.:

```
{
   attr1: 123,
   attr2: "xyz",
   attr3: [{v1: 1, v2: 2}, {v1: 3, v2: 4}]
}
```

I would like to create a class or an interface in typescript to enforce this representation, like httpClient.get< MyObject >()

This "MyObject" should have two characteristics:

1) it should be easily defined directly using something like:

```
{attr1: number, attr2: string, attr3: Array<{v1: number, v2: number}>}
```

meaning without using constructors, declaring class properties, and verbose code

2) it should be able to contain some methods, like:

```
is_greater_than_onehunded() {
  return this.attr1 > 100;
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to "model" a json structure in ts?

Answer (score -1):

```
    export class YourType{
    {
    attr1: number; 
    attr2: string; 
    attr3: Array<{v1: number, v2: number}>
    is_greater_than_onehunded() {
           return this.attr1 > 100;
        }
    }
```

And there you go